# Instead of NULL how do I show `0` in result with SELECT statement sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one `stored procedure` which is giving me an output (I stored it in a #temp table) and that output I'm passing to another `scalar function`.

> Instead of NULL how do I show `0` in result with SELECT statement sql?

For example stored proc is having select statement like follwing :

```
SELECT Ename , Eid , Eprice , Ecountry from Etable
Where Ecountry = 'India'
```

Which is giving me output like

```
Ename    Eid    Eprice    Ecountry
Ana      12     452       India
Bin      33     NULL      India
Cas      11     NULL      India
```

Now instead of showing `NULL` how can I show price as `0` ?

What should be mention in `SELECT` statement to make `NULL` as `0` ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [`coalesce()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
select  coalesce(Eprice, 0) as Eprice
```

In SQL Server only, you can save two characters with [`isnull()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

```
select  isnull(Eprice, 0) as Eprice
```

Comment: perhaps this should be `select  coalesce(Eprice, 0) as Eprice` to preserve the column name?

Comment: @EdHarper: Sure, good idea.  @ashuthinks: Both work the same.  `coalesce()` will work in other databases besides SQL Server.

Comment: Hi Thanks which is better to use 1. coalesce(Eprice, 0)` 2. isnull(Eprice, 0)

Comment: @ashuthinks See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx

Comment: Something @X.L.Ant 's link doesn't mention is that `ISNULL()` is generally faster (assuming your needs allow you to functionally use either operation).

Comment: It appears both are considerably (and quite ridiculously) slow, at least for my purposes.

Comment: For anyone using MySQL, `IFNULL` should be used instead of `ISNULL`. In MySQL `ISNULL` takes one parameter and return 0 or 1. `IFNULL` will return the first argument if it is not null, and the second argument if it is.

Answer (score 8):

Try these three alternatives:

```
1. ISNULL(MyColumn, 0)

2. SELECT CASE WHEN MyColumn IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE MyColumn END FROM MyTable

3. SELECT COALESCE(MyCoumn, 0) FROM MyTable
```

There is another way but it is not supported by most of the databases
    SELECT MyColumn + 0
This might work, but NULL + anything is still NULL in T-SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Try `ISNULL(Eprice, 0)` instead of `Eprice`

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
SELECT Ename , Eid , ISNULL(Eprice, 0) as Eprice, Ecountry from Etable
Where Ecountry = 'India'
```

Comment: +1 [Two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_707) [planes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_727) in your username lol

Comment: Oh yeah.. and I was thinking about changing it ^^

Answer (score 1):

CASE WHEN price IS NULL THEN  0 ELSE price END

Answer (score 0):

One more difference, if you would get 0 for "Null or Empty" string use coalesce :

```
select isnull('', 0) as result => ''
select coalesce('', 0) as result => 0
```

And both return 0 for null value

```
select isnull(null, 0) as result => 0
select coalesce(null, 0) as result => 0
```