# SQL returning NULL instead of 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT max(s.id), c.id, s.time, s.rankxp, s.score, s.kills, s.deaths, s.headshots, s.rank 
FROM clients c, stats s 
WHERE c.id = s.client_id  && s.client_id = 123
```

This query works fine if the client_id can be found in the stats table.  However if the client_id can't be found in the stats table, the query is returning null instead of 0 rows.

How can I make this query return 0 rows instead of null when the client isn't found in the stats table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instead of NULL how do I show \`0\` in result with SELECT statement sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667148/instead-of-null-how-do-i-show-0-in-result-with-select-statement-sql)

Comment: @Gnarlywhale this is about zero rows not `0` the number. Presumably a side effect of using the non standard and not guaranteed MySQL feature allowing mixing aggregated and non aggregated columns without a group by.

Comment: @duffy356 You should fix the last line of the where clause with `s.client_id = 123`

Comment: I think its because of the max() function try this `SELECT IFNULL(max(s.id),0), c.id, s.time, s.rankxp, s.score, s.kills, s.deaths, s.headshots, s.rank 
FROM clients c, stats s 
WHERE c.id = s.client_id  && s.client_id =123`

Comment: you know that aggregation function like `max` cannot work without `group by` according ansi sql standard, the fact that mysql allows it doesnt matter, rewrite your query to meet standard, it will probably fix your problem or at least you will be able to fix behaviour

Answer (score 1):

If client ID always exists in clients table, just use a left join.

```
SELECT max(s.id), c.id, s.time, s.rankxp, s.score, s.kills, s.deaths, s.headshots, s.rank FROM clients c Left Join stats s on c.id = s.client_id Where c.id=123
```

This will give you a NULL in the max(s.id) field though.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `SELECT max(s.id), c.id, s.time, s.rankxp, s.score, s.kills, s.deaths, s.headshots, s.rank FROM clients c, stats s WHERE c.id = s.client_id && s.client_id=123` with an = between s.client_id and 123?

Comment: No, that's the point. Needs to be a left join. the c.id=s.client_id goes in the ON phrase, and the c.id=123 goes in the WHERE filter. Original query is an inner join, which will return zero rows unless the ID value exists in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to get latests stats for the client, to do this you don't need to do any joins, try this one:

```
SELECT s.id, s.client_id, s.time, s.rankxp, s.score, s.kills, s.deaths, s.headshots, s.rank 
FROM stats s 
WHERE s.client_id = 123
ORDER BY s.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm able to force a record with 0 values to be returned by using a duplicate sql statement unioned with the first.  Such as:

```
SELECT 0 ID, 123 ClientID, 0 STime, 0 RankXP, 0 Score, 0 Kills, 0 Deaths, 0 Headshots, 0 rank
from stats s
where s.client_id = 123
UNION
select s.id ID, s.client_id ClientID, s.time STime, s.rankxp RankXP, s.score Score, s.kills Sills, s.deaths Deaths, s.headshots Headshots, s.rank Rank
from stats s
where s.client_id = 123
```

In my case, I encase the whole query within another query which selects the sum, count or max of the query elements, and refers to the main query as "Inner-table".