# I want to get the result as zero rather than an empty array when there is no records in the table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter-3

Here is the code block and this results an empty array but I want the result to be zero when it’s like that.

```
public function step_count($data,$count)
{ 
    $values=array();
    for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) { 
        $query3=$this->db->query("SELECT `check` FROM `staffsalary` WHERE `user_id` = '$data[$i]' AND `month` = '02'");
        $result3 = $query3->result();
        array_push($values,$results3);
    }
    return $values;
}
```

This results an empty array, but i want the result as 0 rather than empty array to show in the view page. How to get the result as 0 when there is no record found in table?

Comment: `return empty($values) ? 0 : $values;`

Comment: when i add this the var_dump results is:array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#28 (1) { ["check"]=> string(1) "1" } } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(0) { } }, there are 3 staffs, the salary was calculated for the 1st staff only so it returns check as 1 and for the other 2 staffs salary was not calculated so i want this as 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instead of NULL how do I show \`0\` in result with SELECT statement sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667148/instead-of-null-how-do-i-show-0-in-result-with-select-statement-sql)

Comment: You can also use IFNULL in your database query. This way you can return the result as '0' instead of null

Comment: the vardump resultis array(3) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#34 (2) { ["total"]=> string(2) "56" ["is_completed"]=> string(1) "8" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#35 (2) { ["tot"]=> string(2) "28" ["completed"]=> string(2) "10" } ["check"]=> int(1) [2]=> object(stdClass)#36 (1) { ["name"]=> string(6) "staff1" } } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#33 (2) { ["total"]=> string(1) "1" ["is_completed"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#32 (2) { ["tot"]=> string(1) "2" ["completed"]=> string(1) "2" } ["check"]=> int(0) [2]=> object(stdClass)#39 (1) { ["name"]=> string(6) "staff2" } }

Comment: now i want to how to show the check using foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CodeIgniter's `num_rows()` function. It will return the number of records found. If no record is found, then it will return 0.

See below:

```
public function step_count($data,$count)
{ 
    $values=array();
    for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) { 
        $query3=$this->db->query("SELECT `check` FROM `staffsalary` WHERE `user_id` 
        = '$data[$i]' AND `month` = '02'");
        $result3 = $query3->num_rows();
        array_push($values,$results3);
    }
    return $values;
}
```

Comment: but it results as not an array

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** using `count()`

```
if(count($values) > 0)
    return $values;
else
    return 0;
```

**Option 2:** using `empty()`

```
if(empty($values))
    return 0;
else
    return $values;
```