# Turn Nulls to 0 USing SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a query but i need the numbers to come out to 0 if they are blank or null.

```
Declare @ReportDate as Date
Set @ReportDate = '2022-07-31'
Declare @Props As int
Set @Props = 707

SELECT
'Occupied' AS strType,
ISNULL(SUM(intOccupied),0) as intUnits,                    
IsNULL(SUM(dblOccupiedArea),0) AS dblSqFt,
IsNULL(SUM(mnyOccupiedPotential),0) AS mnyGPI,
ISNULL(SUM(mnyOccupiedRent),0) mnyOccRent,
ISNULL(Sum(intOccupied),0) /CAST(Sum(intOccupied) + Sum(intVacant) + Sum(intDamaged) as float) As 'OccupiedPercent',
ISNULL(SUM(dblOccupiedArea),0) /CAST(Sum(dblOccupiedArea) + Sum(dblVacantArea) + Sum(dblDamagedArea) as float) As 'SQFTPercent',
Sum(dblOccupiedArea) / sum(intOccupied) as mnyAverageSize,
IsNull(Sum(mnyOccupiedRent),0) / Cast(Sum(mnyOccupiedPotential) + Sum(mnyVacantPotential) + Sum(mnyDamagedPotential) as float) as mnyECONOcc,
SUM(mnyOccupiedRent) / SUM(mnyOccupiedPotential) as OccupiedVariance,
(SUM(mnyOccupiedRent) / SUM(mnyOccupiedPotential)) / Cast(Sum(mnyOccupiedPotential) + Sum(mnyVacantPotential) + Sum(mnyDamagedPotential) as float) as 'OccupiedVariancePercent',
1 AS intOrder
FROM tblUBMReport
LEFT JOIN tblUBMInsuranceShare ON tblUBMInsuranceShare.intProp = tblUBMReport.intProp
WHERE tblUBMReport.intProp IN (@Props) AND dtReport = @ReportDate
UNION
SELECT
'Vacant' AS strType,
ISNULL(SUM(intVacant),0) as intUnits,                    
ISNULL(SUM(dblVacantArea),0) AS dblSqFt,
ISNULL(SUM(mnyVacantPotential),0) AS mnyGPI,
ISNULL(Sum(intVacant),0) /CAST(Sum(intOccupied) + Sum(intVacant) + Sum(intDamaged) as float) As 'VaccantPercent',
ISNULL(SUM(dblVacantArea),0) /CAST(Sum(dblOccupiedArea) + Sum(dblVacantArea) + Sum(dblDamagedArea) as float) As 'SQFTPercent',
NULL AS mnyOccRent,
NULL AS mnyVacantECON,
Sum(dblVacantArea) / sum(intVacant) as mnyAverageSize,
Null as mnyVariance,
Null as mnyVacantVarPercentage,

2 AS intOrder
FROM tblUBMReport
LEFT JOIN tblUBMInsuranceShare ON tblUBMInsuranceShare.intProp = tblUBMReport.intProp
WHERE tblUBMReport.intProp IN (@Props) AND dtReport = @ReportDate
UNION
SELECT
'Damaged' AS strType,
ISNULL(SUM(intDamaged),0) as intUnits,                    
ISNULL(SUM(dblDamagedArea),0) AS dblSqFt,
ISNULL(SUM(mnyDamagedPotential),0) AS mnyGPI,
NULL AS mnyOccRent,
NULL as mnyDamageECON,
ISNULL(Sum(intDamaged),0) /CAST(Sum(intOccupied) + Sum(intVacant) + Sum(intDamaged) as float) As 'DamagedPercent',
ISNULL(SUM(dblDamagedArea),0) /CAST(Sum(dblOccupiedArea) + Sum(dblVacantArea) + Sum(dblDamagedArea) as float) As 'SQFTPercent',
Sum(dblDamagedArea) / sum(intDamaged) as mnyAverageSize,
NULL as mnyVariance,
Null as mnyDamagedVarPercentage,


3 AS intOrder
FROM tblUBMReport
LEFT JOIN tblUBMInsuranceShare ON tblUBMInsuranceShare.intProp = tblUBMReport.intProp
WHERE tblUBMReport.intProp IN (@Props) AND dtReport = @ReportDate
ORDER BY intOrder
```

Comment: and your question is what ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instead of NULL how do I show \`0\` in result with SELECT statement sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667148/instead-of-null-how-do-i-show-0-in-result-with-select-statement-sql)

Comment: What do you mean with "blank"? That suggests your numbers aren't numbers but strings

Comment: How can a number be blank? Are they stored as char/varchar?

Comment: if the column can be either blank or a NULL then you need a case statemente around it to always return 0. case when isnull(yourcolum,0)='' then 0 else  isnull(yourcolum,0) end

Comment: If *some* numbers can be NULL , you should be using `SUM(ISNULL(intOccupied,0)) as intUnits` so that it doesn't return NULL when there are other values in a column.